# Unable to install the sonata media bundle

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-2.8, sonata-media-bundle

I have installed the sonata media bundle and getting following errors.

Here is my composer.json file.

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3,>=2.3.10",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.13",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^2.1",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "^3.3",
        "symfony/security-acl": "^3.0",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "^2.1",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.2",
        "vich/uploader-bundle": "^1.4",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.1",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.4",

        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^3.5",
        "kutny/autowiring-bundle": "^1.0",
        "ginq/ginq": "^0.2.4",
        "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^2.5",
        "knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "^1.5",
        "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "^3.2",
        "egeloen/ckeditor-bundle": "^5.0",
        "oneup/uploader-bundle": "~1.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.8-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging my code. I have found the problem. Sonatamediabundle is conflicting with KutnyAutowiringBundle , which I am using for autowiring in my project. I did not find the exact solution but removing the KutnyAutowiringBundle solve the problem.